# Can we download the same uploaded pdf document in svg format?

Tags: apex, trigger

I uploaded some documents in folder in Document Object in pdf, now I want to download this document in svg, png and pdf format. Now I am able to download this in pdf format only.

Is there any to convert the MIME type of the document while downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

No. Salesforce doesn't allow this functionality of Online Conversion. You need to manually convert them or need to use any third party API.

Nativelly in SF this is not possible.

You can try this http://www.convertapi.com/